# how to get only 2 digits after decimal point?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server 2012

My output is 24.242553, but I need only 2 digits after my decimal point.

Here is my query :

```
AVG(cast(dbo.vw_NEW_UG.SCORE_A20 as decimal))AS ACT_SUPER_SCORE
```

I also tried this, but its not working.

```
AVG(cast(dbo.vw_NEW_UG.SCORE_A20 as decimal(10,2)))AS ACT_SUPER_SCORE
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ROUND` is probably the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROUND` function like this

```
CAST( ROUND(AVG(cast(dbo.vw_NEW_UG.SCORE_A20 as decimal) ) , 2 )  AS decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: This is giving me 24.240000

Answer (score 1):

Move your cast to the outside of your average function and try that:

```
cast(AVG(dbo.vw_NEW_UG.SCORE_A20) as decimal)AS ACT_SUPER_SCORE
```

Comment: You can try       SELECT CONVERT(REAL, round(12.34567,2))